# Starting mysql with --skip-grant-tables option disabled

Tags: mysql

I managed to start my local mysql server with the `--skip-grant-tables` option enabled using the command `sudo mysql --skip-grant-tables`. Now even after I restarted the machine, the mysql server is running with `skip-grant-tables` enabled. How do I restart mysql server normally, i.e., without the `skip-grant-tables` option.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 1):

If you modified the config file or the startup file of mysql server, you need to discard these changes.

If you just ran it manually using `sudo mysqld`, you need to kill it manually also using `kill`. Then, you should be able to start it normally using `/etc/init.d/mysql start` or `service mysql start`.

Comment: +1 on this. Instead of killing mysqld, you could also do `mysqladmin shutdown` to mysqld shut down in a clean, orderly manner.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: I don't mean using `kill -9` as this may cause data loss or tables corruption. I mean just `kill` using `SIGTERM`.